# Javascript: Average Grade and Letter Grade of Students

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I was looking at this Javascript code to calculate the average grade of an array of students and then based on the result decide which letter grade should be assigned. I was wondering how would you display these two results in your HTML? I've played around and tried a few things but nothing seems to work. I'm also new to Javascript so the solution is most likely very simple but I'm just not sure how to go about it.

```js
var students = [80, 77, 88, 95, 68];

var Avgmarks = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  Avgmarks += students[i][1];
  var avg = (Avgmarks / students.length);
}

console.log("Average grade: " + (Avgmarks) / students.length);

if (avg < 60) {
  console.log("Grade : F");
} else if (avg < 70) {
  console.log("Grade : D");
} else if (avg < 80) {
  console.log("Grade : C");
} else if (avg < 90) {
  console.log("Grade : B");
} else if (avg < 100) {
  console.log("Grade : A");
}
```

EDIT: 09/10/2019

I have revised my code to this:

```js
let students = [80, 77, 88, 95, 68];

let avgMarks = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  avgMarks += students[i];
}

let avg = avgMarks / students.length;

if (avg <= 60) {
  document.write("Grade : F");
} 
else if (avg <= 70) {
  document.write("Grade : D");
} 
else if (avg <= 80) {
  document.write("Grade : C");
}
else if (avg <= 90) {
  document.write("Grade : B");
} else {
  document.write("Grade : A");
}

document.getElementById("studentAvgGrade").innerHTML = avg;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Average Student Grade and Letter Grade</title>
</head>

<body>
 
   <div id="studentAvgGrade"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

My code is now working. Thank you everyone for your help.

I would however like to know if this is the best way to go about solving the task using pure Javascript or is there a better way?

Comment: select an element and replace it's text with grade?

Comment: You should set `avg` after the loop is done, not every time.

Comment: And you should use it in the `console.log()` call, not recompute it there.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just replace the calls to `console.log()` with `document.getElementById(something).innerText = ...`

Comment: Show what you've played around with, so we can help you fix it. We're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the element with

```
const element = document.querySelector(YOUR HTML ELEMENT SELECTOR);
```

Then inside each if statement

```
element.innerText = grade
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare a new variable for grade:
let grade = ""
then inside of your if/else statement variable grade gets assigned a new value with each condition.

in your html select the element where you would want it to appear and then assign variable grade as its innerhtml.:

```
<h1 id='grading'></h1>
```

and in your js:

```
let grade = ""
if (avg < 60){
      console.log("Grade : F");   
      grade = "F"   
      } 
    else if (avg < 70) {
            console.log("Grade : D"); 
            grade = "D"
              } 
    else if (avg < 80) 
         {
            console.log("Grade : C"); 
            grade = "C"
    } else if (avg < 90) {
            console.log("Grade : B");
            grade = "B" 
    } else if (avg < 100) {
            console.log("Grade : A"); 
            grade = "A"
}

const gradeToDisplay = document.getElementById("grading")
grading.innerHTML = grade
```

Comment: it can also be set as innerText